# How to customize posts in WordPress by using HTML and CSS?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, posts

I've tried to find the information on the Internet and stackoverflow, but there is nothing about it.

So I've migrated my website(html,css,js) to WordPress(index.php,header.php,footer.php etc) and I can't figure out how to change a view of posts before adding them to my site.

I can see 4 ways of doing that:

1)Download WP plugin to add and customize posts.
But I'll only be able to customize it by using the admin area, I can't do it with HTML and CSS, very few options(color,picture etc)

2)Create a separate file(sidebar.php) and add to it my posts.
But if my client wants to add posts himself, he won't be able to do that, and again very few options.
[example](http://prntscr.com/lhmhoy)

3)Use the standard "Posts-Add New" in the admin area.
But in that case, I can't figure out how to cusomize it, what shall I do?Go into the "wp-admin" folder which is in the WordPress file and find HTML,CSS which are responsible for changing posts view and change them? Because if I don't change them, this happens [example](http://prntscr.com/lhmk36)

4) Migrate my website to WordPress by using a blank theme [example](https://underscores.me/).
There is a posts page(posts.php,I don't remeber how it's called exactly) and try to find a code snippet which is responsible for a posts view

My question is how to change a view of posts in WordPress? And this is what I want to make [example](http://prntscr.com/lhmm7d) [link to the website](http://www.themechampion.com/demo/industriallive/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is opinion-based and more relevant to [wordpress.se].

Comment: You can customize visual look of by custom css.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite broad so my answer will be broad as well. Option 4 is what I do when developing WP sites, but using Understrap + Understrap [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) (it is  Bootsrap 4 based and I love this). I receive and empty theme (no styles) with couple of page + layout templates for start. From this point when you have your empty theme you can start adding your [custom template files](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/) and style it as you want. You'll need to spend some time in order to understand how to [add custom CSS + JS](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) files inside the functions.php
 and depending of your php skills some time in order to how to output your posts/pages content.